# Google Search doesn't show "More results from <domain>"

Tags: google-search

It used to be that if a search results in many results from a website then a link would be displayed to show `More results from <domain>`

For instance when you search for "ukraine conflict" then Google returns 2 links to the Washington Post about the Ukraine conflict, but the link to show more results from the Washington Post is missing. It seems some update to the search algorithm or search display did this.

- Is there any extension or setting to get the link to more results from a certain domain back?
- Is there a way to show more than 2 results per domain? For instance questions about programming will often lead to answers from "Stackoverflow" being grouped.

I am aware that search queries can be edited to include `site:washingtonpost.com`

Example when searching for `ruby list comprehension`:

- You can see that there is a result grouping for `Stackoverflow.com`
- You see there are two results from `Reddit.com`, but no button to show more.

[image: Google Search for 'ruby list comprehension']

As a counter-example, when searching for `node` there is a link to show more results from `nodejs.org` (interestingly Wikipedia doesn't seem to have sufficient results for `node` to show a separate link to more results).

[image]

Comment: Have you already tried searching in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled and using a different web-browser ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried incognito in Firefox and Chrome without any extensions. It seems Google has reduced the amount of "Show more from <domain>" links quite a lot.